# Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class gg/ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, maps

Hello I've been using R for around a year now but only in my spare time outside of work and I've encountered the following error whilst trying to create a graph on ggplot:

```
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class gg/ggplot
```

I see the error message when trying to create any of the 3 graphs below.

```
BookingData %>%
ggplot() %>%
geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Destination))

BookingData %>%
ggplot() %>%
geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Cost))

BookingData %>%
ggplot() %>%
geom_point(mapping = aes(x = Destination, y = Cost))
```

The data I'm analysing is:

```
str(BookingData)
'data.frame':   8583 obs. of  7 variables:
$ Person.URN  : int  4087 39748 294410 366031 692418 841419 1018069 46055 
253036 484387 ...
$ Booking.URN : int  9298 79548 548230 697854 1314354 1594476 1930719 91905 
472923 921033 ...
$ Destination : Factor w/ 15 levels "Australia","Denmark",..: 4 4 11 3 15 5 
1 1 4 15 ...
$ Continent   : Factor w/ 5 levels "Africa","Americas",..: 5 5 5 5 2 5 4 4 5 
2 ...
$ Product     : Factor w/ 3 levels "Accommodation Only",..: 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 
3 3 ...
$ Cost        : int  629 1047 454 798 676 1073 482 587 1217 532 ...
$ Booking.Date: Date, format: "2009-09-19" "2009-09-19" ...
```

Any help you can provide on why I'm seeing this error message and how I can correct it would be much appreciated.

Comment: ggplot doesn't accept %>%. Try BookingData %>% ggplot()+geom_bar

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although @A.Suliman 's suggestion will very likely solve the problem, it is good etiquette to provide, in general, some *small* sample data in order to reproduce your problem. If you don't want to create a sample data frame, then I suggest to use for example dput() instead of str()

Answer (score 2):

Because I cannot reproduce your data, I'm using `mtcars` dataset.
Your main mistake was the use of pipe (%>%) instead of  + . 
In addition, I prefer to put the `aes()` (x\y axis) under the `ggplot()` and not under the other argument.

For example:

```
require(tidyverse)

df <- mtcars

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(vs))) +
  geom_bar()

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) +
  geom_point()
```

You can look [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/) for more explanations and examples.

Comment: Oh my days, I knew it would be some ridiculous error on my part. Thanks a lot much appreciated

Comment: It's usually something like this ;) . You're welcome and glad I could help.

Comment: @DJV I generally agree with creating the mapping within the ggplot() call. However, if you're creating more complex plots based on more than one data ... in this case it can be *very* useful to create mappings within each plot- call.. Saying this - it is then the only way... ;)